# Differentiability of single-variable function

Tags: calculus

I learn from my maths lesson that there is another way to define differentiability.

Suppose *f:R $\rightarrow$ R*

*f(x)=f(a)+f'(x)(x-a)+E(x)*  for some *x* near *a* and *E(x)* is the error term.

So f is differentiable if

$\lim \limits_{x \to a} \frac{E(x)}{(x-a)} =0$

But the above definition is based on the assumption that $f'(x)$ exists first

So my question is: is this definition suitable? It seems that it turns into a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is a $c\in \mathbb{R}$ and a function $E : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, s.t. $f(x) = f(a) + c(x-a)+E(x)$ near $a$ and $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{E(x)}{x-a} = 0$. Then:

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-c = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)-c(x-a)}{x-a} = 0$$
So that means: $f'(x)$ exists and $f'(x)=c$. Of course writing $f'(x)$ instead of $c$ before you know this is indeed begging the question.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way it ought to be interpreted. For a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, suppose that there exist *a real number* $A$ such that for all $x$ in some neighborhood of $a$,
$$
f(x)=f(a)+A(x-a)+E(x)
$$
and that
$$
\lim \limits_{x \to a} \frac{E(x)}{(x-a)} =0
$$
,we say that $f$ is differentiable at $a$. If $f$ is differentiable at $a$  we *define* $f'(a)$ by
$$
f'(a)=A
$$
This definition is not circular and is useful since it can be generalized to the case where $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$. In this case $A$ is a *matrix* instead of a *real number* (to be precise, $A$ is a linear operator).